# React-native - Alert.alert, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For unknown reasons my Alert.alert refuse to work. I am basically reusing the code from earlier where it is working. Getting the error:

> Exception NSArrayl length; unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x170623440 was thrown while invoking alertWithArgs on targer
>   Alertmanager with params.

Thanks

```
acceptFriendRequest(friendsName){
    Alert.alert(
      friendsName + ' wants to add you',
      [
        {text: 'Decline', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel',
      },
      {text: 'Accept', onPress: () =>  this.confirmFriendRequest(this), style: 'accept'},

    ],
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the second argument ([the alert body message](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html#alert)), which you can use `undefined`/`null` if you don't need a body message:

```
Alert.alert(`${friendsName} wants to add you`, undefined, [
  {
    text: 'Decline',
    onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
    style: 'cancel',
  },
  { text: 'Accept', onPress: () => this.confirmFriendRequest() },
]);
```

You might need to close your app fully and restart it after applying the changes due to a [bug in RN](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18439).

Also note:

- `style: 'accept'` is not valid and will be ignored.
- you don't need to pass `this` as argument to `this.confirmFriendRequest()`.

Comment: The thing that saved me here was your reference to **fully restarting the app**. Thanks!